# ec2 instance ssh access blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I was trying just for fun to configure an openvpn server on an ec2 instance. After the last reboot I wasn't able to connect anymore to my instance; the following is the client log:

```
    macbrein:~ renato$ ssh ec2-user@52.62.20.211 -i .ssh/ec2-openvpn.pem -vvv
    OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/renato/.ssh/config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 52.62.20.211 [52.62.20.211] port 22.
    debug1: connect to address 52.62.20.211 port 22: Connection refused
    ssh: connect to host 52.62.20.211 port 22: Connection refused
```

this is the last log of the instance (retrieved in the aws control panel):

```
Starting openvpn: [10.975933] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6 [10.979593] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
Enter Private Key Password:
```

apparently openvpn is stuck because it's prompting for the private key's password and I think this is blocking everything else, might this be the problem?
This is not a production machine, i can simply terminate it and start a new one from scratch, but I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate way to deal with this kind of problems!

thank you!

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.